# Number+씩 (하나씩 둘씩 셋씩)

Tags: grammar

Number + Counter + 씩.  한 명씩 means person at a time. Right ?

If I want to use “Number+씩” Do I not have to shorten 하나 to 한 ?

I just know that If I want to use Number+Counter I have to shorten

1-4. 하나 +  명(Counter) = 한 명씩. I saw 하나씩 so this makes me confused

Is this 씩 a counter ? Or is it exempt from this rule  ?

Answer (score 2):

The number 하나, 둘, 셋, 넷 (and all numbers ending in these, like 11: 열하나) get abbreviate to 한, 두, 세, 네 when they are followed by a count word like 명(for counting people), 개 (for counting things) or 마리 (for counting animals) - [more examples here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_count_word).  Without a count word, the long forms like 하나 should be used

So we say 하나 or 한 명.

"-씩" in 하나씩 or 한 명씩 is not a count word, it is a 접사 (a derivational suffix or possibly a [clitic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clitic)).  So when it gets added to 하나, 하나 doesn't change to 한 - there is no count word here.

Thus, we can say either 하나씩 or 한 명씩, but we can't say 한씩.

Comment: Can I ask you another question ? What 하나둘씩 means ?